# C# - populate combobox using DataBoundItems

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2013, combobox

Maybe I ask a stupid question but, I would like to populate a combobox with values from a database by clicking the small arrow "UseDataBoundsItems" (Visual Studio 2013) and I constantly get these errors:

> Error 2   The type name 'TMJudeteDataSetTableAdapters' does not exist in the type 'TransManager.TransManager' D:\Proiect practica\TransManager\TransManager\formulareAdaugare\formularAddOras.Designer.cs 44  56  TransManager
>   Error   1   The type name 'TMJudeteDataSet' does not exist in the type 'TransManager.TransManager'  D:\Proiect practica\TransManager\TransManager\formulareAdaugare\formularAddOras.Designer.cs 42  53  TransManager

Need some suggestions. Thanks!

** I mention that the combobox is part of a GroupBox!